# What's the best way to clean and dry blueberries?

Tags: fruit, produce, blueberries

I buy organic blueberries which come in a little plastic container.  I like to wash them and put them in a tupperware container.  After I wash them I place them between some paper towels to let them dry, but they take forever to dry this way.

Is there a better way to this?

Comment: If your concern is to avoid storing them wet, you can actually wait to wash them until you're about to use them.

Comment: Good point, but not always possible -- if I'm packing someone's lunch, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the same method I would use.

If you have a salad spinner you could try giving them a gentle spin in there first.  They are sturdy enough (unless they're over-ripe) that they should handle a gentle pass through it.